# Android application changing from background to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having an app A with Settings and Authentication activities. The Authentication activity is launched whenever some other app(say App B) is launched, so if the authentication is successful then app B's launcher Activity is shown(a kind of app lock protection). I have two behaviors to explain here,

1. When I'm having my App A minimized, I will launch App B. This will trigger the Authentication activity of App A. If the authentication is successful then immediately I'm killing the Authentication Activity using finish(). But this will finish the Authentication activity and it will bring the activity of App A that was minimized previously to front(I don't want this to happen) instead of taking it to new app.
2. If the App A is not running at all(not even minimized) than the Authentication activity is launched and on successful authentication the App B's activity is shown.

Can someone explain me why these 2 different behaviors are being shown. Also in case 1 also I want to show the Activity of app 2 after successful Authentication.

Comment: Are you using StartActivityForResult?

Comment: No.. Just StartActivity().

Comment: Have a look at it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: can you post the Codes, specially of Activity A and of triggering your Authentication activity

Comment: I'm looking for app launches from packagemanager and whenever a package is launched I'm launching the AuthenticationActivity using startActivity().

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for some thing like this. 
But i did find some solutions which were out of syllabus for me like using background service or using getTasks method or using package manager like so on.

The simplest solution which i made was some thing like this.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private static boolean background = false;
private static int count = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
   if(background){
       background = false;
       Log.v("activityFocus", "Activity came in foreground ");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foreground", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    count++;
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    count--;
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
 if(count==0){
     Log.v("activityFocus", "Activity is in background ");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     background=true;
 }
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

}
```

}